# How to separate gpu drivers from gnome shell

Tags: linux, fedora, drivers, nvidia, gnome-shell

my goal is to separate the GPU drivers from all processes that are using them. lsof /dev/nvidia* tells me what processes I need to kill, after killing all the processes my PC is rebooting because gnome shell is using the drivers.Can I somehow kill the process without losing control of my PC ?

Thanks.

Comment: Use your console.

Comment: I m using my console :D :D Well I could try to connect over SSH and try it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can't. Your graphical interface *is* being rendered by the GPU, that's its job. If you don't want that, don't use a graphical interface. Or, use a separate graphics card just for the graphical interface.

Comment: That makes sens , thank you ! :)